# Contribution Detail Report- "contact name suffix" isn't showing up as one of the possible report criteria

Tags: civireport

I'm trying to create a Contribution Detail Report and the "contact name suffix" isn't showing up as one of the possible report criteria. Please advise!

Answer (score 1):

Allison, you're correct, neither prefix nor suffix is available (surprising) 
Assuming that coding isn't an option.  There are several ways to can export the contacts prefix/suffix.  For example You can...

Create report you want and include civicrm "contact ID"

If you can also create a contribution search that returns the same contacts, then you can export the search results and include the suffix field.

If you can't create a contribution search, then you can do an import "Update" and add a "tag" that will identify the contacts in your report (match on contact ID) You can then run a search and export the suffix.

If you'd like the report to include suffix, you can submit a request to the [paid issue queue](https://civicrm.org/paid-issue-queue) and the Core team will give you an estimate on what it will cost to add suffix.  Seems like a good way to contribute back a function that others would like as well.